# Are generalized cohomology theories a homotopy category of some category of invariants?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, cohomology, model-categories, stable-homotopy

I was taught to think of generalized cohomology theories as the homotopy category of (symmetric) spectra. But is there also a category of 'invariants', that is, some category of contravariant functors from a suitable category of topological spaces to a suitable category of algebraic objects, which has a model category structure such that the homotopy category gives the category of generalized cohomology theories, without referring to spectra?

If such a thing exists, why do people prefer to use spectra?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here is a short argument why we don't expect generalized cohomology theories to behave so well.

In the stable homotopy category, there is a generalized homology/cohomology theory represented by the sphere spectrum $S$, so that $S_*(X)$ are the stable homotopy groups of $X$.  It has a multiplication-by-2 self-map $f$ and we can use the triangulated structure to find an exact triangle $S \stackrel{f}{\to} S \to M \to S[1]$ where $S[1]$ is the suspension (equivalently, the shift) of $S$.  We think of $M$ as "the sphere mod 2", and it is called the mod-2 Moore spectrum.

In most derived categories coming from algebra, such an exact triangle would have the property that the multiplication-by-2 map on $M$ was zero.  However, we know that this is not the case here; the multiplication-by-2 map is not zero, but the multiplication-by-4 map is.

One of the problems with using a "functor" language to get at generalized cohomology theories is that given a natural transformation $E \to F$ of generalized cohomology theories, it is not clear what the associated cofiber should be in order to produce a triangulated structure.  Spectra have a natural triangulated structure and they rectify this problem.  (A map between spectra also includes "phantom" data that isn't easily detected by the natural transformation between associated generalized cohomology theories.)

Comment: When you said "the identity self-map actually has order 4", did you mean that "the multiplication-by-2 self-map has order 4"?

Comment: I mean that 4 * id = 0, but 2 * id is not zero.  Sorry.

Answer (score 13):

An even more compelling reason is that stable natural transformations between generalized cohomology theories on *spaces* form the wrong category, i.e. are not the same as the morphisms of the stable category. Let $E,F$ be generalized cohomology theories. Let $Z_n$ be the terms of the $\Omega$-spectrum of a CW model of $E$. Then, more or less by definition, stable natural transformations from $E$ to $F$ are the inverse limit of $F^nZ_n=F^0\Sigma^{\infty-n}Z_n$. This is the correct Hom set in the stable homotopy category when $\lim^1=0$, but this may not be the case (for example when $E=S$, $F$ is the wedge of $\Sigma^n HZ/2$ over $n\in \mathbb{Z}$).

Comment: Welcome to MO, Professor Kriz!